# How to narrow type of parameter in function?

Tags: typescript, union, type-inference

I have type narrow problem. how to narrow type of parameter v to successfully pass it ot funcAorB?

```
// type.d.ts
export type A = "A1" | "A2";
export type B = "B1" | "B2";
export type U = A | B;

export function funcAorB(v: A) : A;
export function funcAorB(v: B) : B;

// test.ts
function wrappFunAorB<T extends U>(v:T) {
  type V<K> = K extends A ? A : B; 
  funcAorB(v as V<T>) // error
}
```

I expected `V<T>` would narrow type of T but is didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've defined `funcAorB` using [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), TypeScript needs to know which specific overload to call (even though either way, it ends up calling the same implementation function). That is, it has to know whether the *runtime* `v` will be an `A` or a `B`. A compile-time check won't work.

You have at least two choices:

1. Implement a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to narrow `v`, for instance:

   ```typescript
   function isA(value: any): value is A {
       return value === "A1" || value === "A2"; // Just an example, you probably want something more robust, where the check and the type have the same single source
   }
   ```

   ...and then use logic so TypeScript sees a narrowed type, for instance:

   ```typescript
   function wrappFunAorB<T extends U>(v :T) {
       if (isA(v)) {
           funcAorB(v);
       } else {
           funcAorB(v);
       }
   }
   ```

   [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAgnlMKCCKC8KARDgIxEoA+xOATEQNwBQoksiyam2AQgcT3JUB9Zq2jwkqDFhQBVfnmo9mLcBI6oAZgFcAdgGMEASxh6Uuwzng8AFADcAXLgCUKZzjHr2Ui-qOm5pYG1nB2Tig8bs4qamySnMEmZn5WNg7OAIZ66C5ZOSgA3kwopShwYAg6cOZ6OgA29SiZAM7NOcwAvkws0mAtCAB0CC1MSYEoAO5wmVBQAGL6oTwAPAAqKJAIYHoAJm1yAHwO7mtuxWUoxlootsYtOA4u5yWXZcHLT8yXnZv1LdgLm9Sh90vYXN8yt1ur0UGtuCgoBVdsYDJltmN-MlzPdHvZMvUdGB8rlnPjCdh7rgiq9ShUqjUUOSiQR8IQSEJKNRmdg2ey6IwUMBUAApHQDdqbCCZAC2UHqYAANCh0DAdIi4DAAEaZLX1dBTbIIFAtGAyyoAC2MegA5igZfBsJqteKEMrJhawBU0J6UAZPQYANbtXY+7AybAWzL2cO+lqy7Ata02hUmtVwAxgJidIA)
2. Implement the function accepting a union type instead, rather than using overloads. It can either directly accept the union:

   ```typescript
   function funcAorB(v: A | B): A | B {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAgnlMKCCKC8KARDgIxEoA+xOATEQNwBQoksiyam2AQgcT3JUB9Zq2jwkqDFhQBVfnmo9mLcBI6oAZgFcAdgGMEASxh6Uuwzng8AFADcAXLmE8AlM6Uo+AbyYoAlDgwBB04cz0dABsolABDAGd4vXRmAF8mFmkwBIQAOgQEpksjU3MAdzg4qCgAMX1rOB4AHgAVFEgEMD0AEyS5AD4HFEdWtxQ-QIt9A0a7ezd0oA)

   Or it can use a generic type parameter:

   ```typescript
   function funcAorB<T extends A | B>(v: T): T {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAgnlMKCCKC8KARDgIxEoA+xOATEQNwBQoksiyam2AQgcT3JUB9Zq2jwkqDFhQBVfnmo9mLcBI6oAZgFcAdgGMEASxh6Uuwzng8APABUUkBGD0ATAM65hPAHwAKADcALhR7AEpQxwBvJhR4lDgwBB04cz0dABtMlABDL1y9dGYAXyYWaTAPBAA6BA8mSyNTcwB3OFyoKAAxfWs4O0dnV095AMCUYIiUWISLfQN+niDw0qA)

Comment: Thanks! It works! I need more your help. Furthermore, how to get return type A if i input type A value? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAgnlMKCCKC8KARDgIxEoA+xOATEQNwBQoksiyam2AQgcT3JUB9Zq2jwkqDFhQBVfnmo9mLcBI6oAZgFcAdgGMEASxh6Uuwzng8APABUUkBGD0ATAM65hPAHwAKADcALhR7AEpQxwBvJhR4lDgwBB04c0DmAF8mFmkwDwQAOgQPJgMzAsT8nQAbBEJLA2s4Hn8ScnCGIA

Comment: @daep93 - In that code, the return type is only `"A1"` because you're passing in a literal, so TypeScript is able to infer a very narrow type. If you passed in something of type `A`, you'd get back `A` (and same for `B`): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAgnlMKCCKC8KARDgIxEoA+xOATEQNwBQoksiyam2AQgcT3JUB9Zq2jwkqDFhQBVfnmo9mLcBI6oAZgFcAdgGMEASxh6Uuwzng8APABUUkBGD0ATAM65hPAHwAKADcALhR7AEpQxwBvJhR4lDgwBB04c0DmAF8mFmkwDwQAOgQPJksjU3NIAEMAWygAGzBSf2rQnHCUWISUAzMCxPydBoR+cus4Hlbw5h7gVASAPQB+JmzykzMnCDrGsFp-ACNQnk7uhL69AaSPYdHCcZsjmbiE+Z6VtaYgA